# Relation between moments and cumulants in Kardar

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

I've been going through Kardar's book and, in the chapter on probability, I found this expression (numbered as $2.13$ in the book):

$$ 
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-ik)^m}{m!} \langle x^m \rangle = \exp \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-ik)^n}{n!} \langle x^n \rangle_c \right] = \prod_n \sum_{p_n} \left[ \frac{(-ik)^{np_n}}{p_n!} \left( \frac{\langle x^n \rangle_c}{n!} \right)^{p_n} \right]
$$

While the first two equalities follow trivially from his definition of $\textit{cumulant generating function}$, I am very intrigued about the expression on the right. Most importantly: how does this product operator arise and what is this $p_n$?

Edit: For better context for those without the book at hand, Kardar defines the $\textit{characteristic function}$ of a Probability Density Function as:
$$
\tilde{p}(k) = \langle e^{-ikx} \rangle = \int e^{-ikx} p(x) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-ik)^n}{n!} \langle x^n \rangle,
$$
while the $\textit{cumulant generating function}$ is its logarithm:
$$
\text{ln}\hspace{0.5mm}\tilde{p}(k) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-ik)^n}{n!} \langle x^n \rangle_c
$$

Comment: The equation in the book has no limits on the final product and sum, and no explanation of $p_ n$? If so, that seems like poor exposition.

Comment: Yes, I've replicated it exactly as is in the book. Kardar directly goes on to match "the powers of $(-ik)^m$ on the two sides"

Comment: I don’t think this is any help, but another way of exponentiating a power series is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147790/exponential-of-formal-power-series-and-bell-polynomials).

Comment: Well, I didn't even know about Bell polynomials, so at least it's interesting haha. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on Math SE since it is purely mathematical.

Comment: Almost certainly the product appears because in the power series of an exponential the argument is raised to powers. So in this case you get sums of products of sums and that somehow gets rearranged to the product of a sum. Look back and make sure that Kardar has never introduced $p_n$ earlier.

Comment: The notation suggests “$n$-th prime” to me, but I don’t think that could be the case here.

Comment: I just checked and this one is indeed the first time it appears.
Anyway, if you know any other reference on moments and cumulants of a probability density function, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression on the right hand side is a simple mathematical deal.

1. The product operator arises because $$\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\cdot \exp(b) \implies \exp(\sum_n a_n)=\prod_n \exp(a_n)$$
2. The sum arises after that because Kardar has expressed $\exp$ as a Taylor series.
   $$\exp(a) = \sum_{p_n} \frac{a^{p_n}}{{p_n}!} \implies \prod_n \exp(a_n) = \prod_n \sum_{p_n} \frac{(a_n)^{p_n}}{{p_n}!}$$

These 2 hints should be enough for you to understand.

Comment: Thanks! Right, I hadn't realized that the exponential had been expanded. So the limits in $n$ and $p_n$ are still $\infty$.